# clang-format: How to align list of struct inits

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

I have an array of structs:
(assume that the identifiers are `#define`d somewhere else...)

```c
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    char id[2+1];
} T;

const T T_list[] = {
    { PRIO_HOUSE, "HI" },
    { PRIO_SOMETHING_ELSE, "WO" }
    // ...
}
```

I would like clang-format to format it like this:

```c
const T T_list[] = {
    { PRIO_HOUSE         , "HI" },
    { PRIO_SOMETHING_ELSE, "WO" }
    // ...
}
```

**Is it possible?**

I already read the docs, but I didnt find something helpful in this regard.
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

This is my `.clang-format`

```
---
BasedOnStyle: WebKit
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BraceWrapping:
  AfterEnum: false  
IndentCaseLabels: 'true'
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: 'true'
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: 'true'
AlignEscapedNewlines: 'true'
AlignTrailingComments: 'true'
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: 'false'
#...
```

Comment: Could probably have done it by hand by now...!

Comment: `clang-format` resets all 'hand-formatting' unless its explicitly disabled for the region.

Comment: So disable it for the region. (But would it really "flatten" these spaces if you added them by hand? That's terrible.) As you say yourself, the documentation doesn't say that this is possible, therefore, it probably isn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of clang-format version 13 (2021) there is a new `AlignArrayOfStructures` option that does exactly this. From the now updated documentation linked in the question:

> `AlignArrayOfStructures (ArrayInitializerAlignmentStyle)` `clang-format 13`
>
> if not None, when using initialization for an array of structs aligns the >fields into columns.

And an example with `AlignArrayOfStructures: Left`:

> ```c
> struct test demo[] =
> {
>    {56, 23,    "hello"},
>    {-1, 93463, "world"},
>    {7,  5,     "!!"   }
> };
> ```

Answer (score 5):

No. `clang-format` cannot do this.

The way I do it is:

1. use a third party tool to align it
2. before the formatted region put: `// clang-format off`
3. after the formatted region put: `// clang-format on`

Comment: In Visual Studio a very useful extension for alignment is: "Code Alignment".

Comment: On my machine, at least, you need a space between `//` and `clang-format...`.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is vertical alignement, you can achieve that with a trailing comma when using initializer lists.

Before

```cpp
    const T T_list[] = { { PRIO_HOUSE, "HI" }, { PRIO_SOMETHING_ELSE, "WO" } };
```

After

```cpp
    const T T_list[] = {
        { PRIO_HOUSE, "HI" },
        { PRIO_SOMETHING_ELSE, "WO" }, // <-- notice the comma here
    };
```

If you further want to align the declarations, I'm unsure how you'd go about it. But the trailing comma is step 1.

Comment: This will also work inside the structs themselves if you want them expanded.