Clang-format break new line for element in array
For example,
I want my array looks like this
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> input = {
        {
            {1, 3, 5, 7}, 
            {10, 11, 16, 20}, 
            {23, 30, 34, 60}
        }, 
        {
            {1, 3, 5, 7}, 
            {10, 11, 16, 20}, 
            {23, 30, 34, 60}
        }
    };

But with clang-format, it makes it less readable
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> input = {{{1, 3, 5, 7}, {10, 11, 16, 20}, {23, 30, 34, 60}}, {{1, 3, 5, 7}, {10, 11, 16, 20}, {23, 30, 34, 60}}};

After checking the clang-format document (verison 20), I'm using 18
AlignArrayOfStructures: Left makes it better but it is still not what I'm trying to achieve.
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> input = {
        {{1, 3, 5, 7}, {10, 11, 16, 20}, {23, 30, 34, 60}},
        {{1, 3, 5, 7}, {10, 11, 16, 20}, {23, 30, 34, 60}}
    };

My current clang-format configuration file,
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass:      true
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      true
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  IndentBraces:    false
  AfterCaseLabel:  true
InsertNewlineAtEOF: true
IncludeBlocks: Merge
#Clang11?: IndentCaseBlocks: true
IndentCaseLabels: true
#Clang11: IndentExternBlock: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentWidth: 4
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Empty
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: All
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 16
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 2
PenaltyBreakString: 64
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 0
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 0
PointerAlignment: Right
ReflowComments: true
SortIncludes: false
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex: '"*PlatformIO.h"'
    Priority: -5
  - Regex: '"*TextIOTypes.h"'
    Priority: -4
  - Regex: '<[Ww]indows.h>'
    Priority: -3
  - Regex: '<*\/.h>'
    Priority: -2
  - Regex: '"*\/.h"'
    Priority: 1

SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: true
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: false
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles: false
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
UseCRLF: false
UseTab: Never
IndentAccessModifiers: true
AlignArrayOfStructures: Left
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: AcrossEmptyLinesAndComments
ColumnLimit: 80
RemoveBracesLLVM: false
RemoveEmptyLinesInUnwrappedLines: true
RemoveSemicolon: true


I am not an expert in this, but which of the ClangFormatStyleOptions did you try ?

@Luuk I'm not sure about your question. If you are asking about my configuration, I left it below the post. If you mean the pre-defined style, I don't use any.

Add a newline between those {{, like is done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70782265/724039
