# VSCode removing spaces with auto format (C/C++)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I recently migrated to VSCode and I really like the auto formatting, but how do I configure it not to remove spaces? I have a sort of matrix I use to configure GPIO pins and I use spaces to make it more readable, but as soon as I save and it auto formats, it destroys the spacing!

example:

```
_InitIO(GPIOA, (GPIO_IN  | GPIO_DN                               ),  //  A0    IRQ-Mag
               (GPIO_IN  | GPIO_DN                               ),  //  A1
               (GPIO_AF7           | GPIO_PP | GPIO_HIGH | GPIO_1),  //  A2
               (GPIO_IN  | GPIO_UP                               ),  //  A3    Switch
```

Turns into:

```
_InitIO(GPIOA, (GPIO_IN | GPIO_DN),                //  A0    IRQ-Mag
                (GPIO_IN | GPIO_DN),                       //  A1
                (GPIO_AF7 | GPIO_PP | GPIO_HIGH | GPIO_1), //  A2
                (GPIO_IN | GPIO_UP),                       //  A3    Switch
```

I have been over all of the formatting options in the settings but can't seem to find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode looks for a file named .clang-format in the workspace directory. See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide#_code-formatting

In order to change the auto-format style, you'll have to create the .clang-format file and modify it according to the [Clang-Format Style Options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

You may have to turn autoformatting off or continuously save the file without formatting using the File: Save without Formatting command through the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) or by using the Ctrl+K Ctrl+Shift+S key combination.

*Edit*

Looks like you want [Disable Formatting on a Piece of Code](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#disabling-formatting-on-a-piece-of-code). It works in VSCode.

Comment: Thank you, so is there no clang option to ignore this, or alternately, to detect patterns like this and enforce them? Sort of like how you can make blocks of comments align with each other as long as there isn't a line without comments between them?

Comment: No problem! I haven't exhaustively checked the Clang-Format documentation, but I doubt a feature to format the code exactly how you want exists since the spacing between `GPIO_AF7` and `GPIO_PP` in the third line is a unique case.

Comment: I did find an answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022831/how-to-make-clang-format-respect-table-like-code-formatting

Comment: I did not know about // clang-format off, thank you! That will suffice enough in my case as I don't have much code that doesn't need formatting.

Comment: While not *quite* what I was looking for, turning off formatting for blocks of code should suffice so it doesn't blow up my table and I can still use auto formatting for most stuff. I will mark this as the answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Alternative

**Avoid code art**

Sometimes its nice to form a pretty table in code, yet to keep that up is *maintenance*.   With good software, maintenance is the most expensive part, so if the code art is difficult to maintain with basic auto-formatting, its value goes down.  It only takes one subsequent maintainer to not have the needed auto format settings to mess things up.

**Avoid code art that is difficult to keep with standard auto-format settings.**

How about the below?  I suspect it will maintain its format with VS and be close enough to meet OP's code art.

```
  _InitIO(GPIOA, // 
      (GPIO_IN | GPIO_DN),                       //  A0 IRQ-Mag
      (GPIO_IN | GPIO_DN),                       //  A1
      (GPIO_AF7 | GPIO_PP | GPIO_HIGH | GPIO_1), //  A2
      (GPIO_IN | GPIO_UP)                        //  A3 Switch
      )
```

Comment: Why bother with defines when you can just assign registers with binary constants? Because it makes it easier to use. The code is for my own use and is specifically so that it makes it more readable for ME. I am not really concerned with the next guy and if I ever pass it on to someone else that uses standard auto formatting they will get the "good enough" result you posted... I don't see why it is a bad thing to do on my end. It works for me and helps me despite the tradeoffs for having to line everything up every once in a while when I change it.

Comment: @Matt I agree you "don't see why it is a bad thing to do on my end.".

Comment: Super helpful... "Hey doc, my knee hurts when I touch it!" "Then don't touch it!"